# Destructuring assignment in generator expressions and array comprehensions

Tags: javascript

Why does `for ([] in object);` work fine but `[void 0 for ([] in object)]` or `(void 0 for ([] in object))` throw a syntax error for invalid left-hand assignment?

For example, I would expect the following code to work, but it doesn't (the assertion isn't even done due to the syntax error):

```
let (
  i = 0,
  iterable = {__iterator__:function() { var i = 5; while (i--) yield i; } }
) {
  for ([] in iterable) i++;
  console.assertEquals([void 0 for ([] in iterable)].length, i);
}
```

Comment: My guess is that they hit different grammar rules: the first for is NOT a generator (it is a for-statement), while the latter is. It doesn't appear that decomposition is supported in that position.

Comment: @Eli: what JS version and engine are you working with? Destructuring in comprehensions and generators works for me in FF 3.6.2/JS 1.8.?, though it chokes on the `let`.

Comment: @outis: Oh sorry I was missing a parenthesis at the end of that generator. It's plain JS 1.8+.

Comment: @Eli: something else strange was going on. I had added the parentheses, but was getting an error message about the `let` keyword. The same thing happens w/ FF 3.6 under both Vista and OS X. I think it all basically comes down to the language features being new.

Comment: @Eli: also note that the assert will fail, because `gen` will reach its end in the first `for` loop. Can generators be rewound? I haven't seen anything about it in the MDC page, but haven't exactly made an effort to find out.

Comment: @outis: Yeah, I'm just going to replace the generator with an iterable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a little digging in `jsparse.c` of SpiderMonkey (which I assume is the JS parser you're using for 1.8 features?)

The `[code for (... in ...)]` format or [generator expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generator_expressions) uses a [different parse function](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/src/jsparse.c#4132) than the [standard `for ([] in obj)`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/src/jsparse.c#2411) uses.

Your LHS error is being [created here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/src/jsparse.c#4200):
 (jsparse.c line 4200)

```
4194           case TOK_LB:
4195           case TOK_LC:
4196             pn3 = DestructuringExpr(cx, &data, tc, tt);
4197             if (!pn3)
4198                 return NULL;
4199 
4200             if (pn3->pn_type != TOK_RB || pn3->pn_count != 2) {
4201                 js_ReportCompileErrorNumber(cx, ts, NULL, JSREPORT_ERROR,
4202                                             JSMSG_BAD_FOR_LEFTSIDE);
4203                 return NULL;
4204             }
```

When it sees the `[` it finds the Destructuring Expression, and ensures the count of the parser node is at 2.

Interestingly enough `[void 0 for ([a,b] in iterator)]` should work, although for reasons I don't care to go digging for, the `b` from `[a,b]` is always undefined:

```
js> [[l1,typeof l2] for ([l1,l2] in {a:1, b:2})]
a,undefined,b,undefined
```

---

For reference - The standard `for([] in {})` uses the following logic to determine the LHS validity:

```
2775 #if JS_HAS_DESTRUCTURING
2776                    ((JSVERSION_NUMBER(cx) == JSVERSION_1_7 &&
2777                      pn->pn_op == JSOP_FORIN)
2778                     ? (pn1->pn_type != TOK_RB || pn1->pn_count != 2)
2779                     : (pn1->pn_type != TOK_RB && pn1->pn_type != TOK_RC)) &&
2780 #endif
```

Which seems to mean that versions other than 1.7 don't require 2 left hand values for this syntax.  The generator expression might be using older parsing logic.  This might be worth submitting as a report to the SpiderMonkey maintainers.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great answer! I'm going to use either `[code for ([,] in ...)]` or `[code for ({} in ...)]` as a workaround until it's fixed.

Comment: @Eli Grey - No problem, it was actually kinda fun to dig into SpiderMonkey and learn how the JS parser actually works on this one. :)